# Capybara select2 helper

Tags: ruby, select, rspec, capybara

Maybe it could help someone. Wrote a simple capybara helper to set values into select2 fields.

See code below.

Comment: what is your question exactly, do you want to ask something or telling something to people.

Comment: It's a great idea to share this, but to fit the SE format, you should refactor this into a question and and answer, both of which you provide.

Comment: Just wanted to share with this piece of code. Thanks for the feedback, refactored into question/answer style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module Features
  module CapybaraHelpers
    def select2(value, element_selector)
      select2_container = first("#{element_selector}")
      select2_container.find(".select2-choice").click

      find(:xpath, "//body").find("input.select2-input").set(value)
      page.execute_script(%|$("input.select2-input:visible").keyup();|)
      drop_container = ".select2-results"
      find(:xpath, "//body").find("#{drop_container} li", text: value).click
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your code just call something like `select2("apple", "#s2id_fruit_id")` and capybara will select `"apple"` value in select2 field with `#s2id_fruit_id` id.

Thanks to [goodwill](https://github.com/goodwill) with his [capybara-select2 gem](https://github.com/goodwill/capybara-select2).

Comment: Thanks! With a little twist, this works on pages with multiple select2 fields and even multi-selects - see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28970538/441379