# Selecting an option with select2 and Capybara running Cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 v4 that loads options through AJAX.
I am running a Cucumber test where I need to select 2 options of the list, but I can't seem to make the list open up and load (which normally gets populated when I type 2 or characters).

I have tried:

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771436/how-to-test-a-select2-element-with-capybara-dsl/18868900):

```
@session.execute_script("$('#publish_to').select2('open')")
```

and

```
@session.first(".input.publish_to .select2-container").click
```

and

```
@session.first("#publish_to").find(".select2-choice").click
```

which do not give me an error, but I am not getting the options to select, so I am assuming that the click is not really working.  Things I have tried to select the options:

```
# This one cannot find the css:
@session.find(".select2-results__options", text: client.email).click

# This one gives me a Timeout error 
@session.evaluate_script "$('#publish_to').val(#{client.id}).trigger('change')"

# This one gives me a Timeout error 
@session.evaluate_script "$('.select2-search__field').trigger('keydown').val('#{client.email}').trigger('keyup')";
sleep 10
@session.find('.select2-search__option', text: client.email).click
```

Anything with `trigger` gives me a Timeout error, so I tried waiting for `jQuery.active` but I never got a `true` even waiting for 2 minutes:

```
counter = 0
 timeout_in_sec = 120
 while counter < timeout_in_sec && @session.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
   sleep 1.second
   counter+=1
 end
```

I tried using the [gem capybara-select2](https://github.com/Hirurg103/capybara_select2) running:
    @session.select2 client.email, css: '#publish_to', search: true
but I get the error `undefined method`select2' for #`and I have`World(CapybaraSelect2)`in my`env.rb`

I am using `Cucumber v3.1.2` with ruby `gem 'cucumber-rails'`

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara? What actions exactly would a user normally do to interact with the page? Are you watching the page in a visible browser while the test is going on?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I'm using poltergeist . The user would usually click the select2, type an email and click one of the options that will display while he types the email. I am not watching the page in a visible browser, how can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poltergeist driver is roughly equivalent to a 7 year old version of Safari which means it doesn't support a lot of current JS/CSS.  This means your issue could simply be that select2 is no longer compatible with Poltergeist (without a lot of polyfilling).  You're going to be much better off updating to using a real browser (stable - chrome via selenium, etc) or one of the direct to Chrome drivers (highly beta) that have spun off Poltergeist ([Apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) is one of them). Those will allow you to run with a visible browser (useful for debugging) or headless.

The following code uses Chrome via selenium and interacts with the select2 demo site to select an entry that is loaded via Ajax.

```
require "selenium/webdriver"
require "capybara/dsl"

sess = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome)
sess.visit("https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax")

sess.first('.select2-container', minimum: 1).click
sess.find('.select2-dropdown input.select2-search__field').send_keys("capy")

sleep 5 # just to watch the browser search

sess.find('.select2-results__option', text: 'teamcapybara/capybara').click

sess.assert_selector(:css, '.select2-selection__rendered', text: 'teamcapybara/capybara')

sleep 5 # just to see the effect
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I had to add I few more classes since I have more select2 in that site and it worked!  Here is the code in case it is useful for the next user:

    `@session.first(".input.publish_to .select2-container").click
    clients.each do |client|
      @session.find('.input.publish_to .select2-search__field').send_keys(client.email)
      @session.find('.select2-results__option', text: client.email).click
      @session.assert_selector(:css, '.publish_to .select2-selection__rendered', text: client.email)
    end`